# .trigger('change') keeps refreshing pagination dataTable after meeting validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Currently, my dataTable has the check button every single row to identify which row desires to do the Update Action. My dataTable used this code

```
var a = $('select[name=table_time_records_length]').val();
$('select[name=table_time_records_length]').append("<option id='optioncount' value='365'></option>");
$('select[name=table_time_records_length]').val(365).trigger('change');
```

To identify all checked rows to update those rows and save to the database. 
This code is working with my dataTable also the saving function of data is working fine. However, the dataTable keeps changing its pagination and going back to page 1 after doing my save function program. I tried to put this code to my ajax.

```
"bStateSave": true
```

I know this code works fine in some of my datatable. But in this case, nothing happens... 
Now currently I'm trying to discover new way just to prevent the dataTable from refreshing its pagination and going back to page1.

Maybe a hardcoded JS will help a lot but I don't know where to start.

I posted only the necessary code that affects my output.

---

My code for showing the data from the database to data Table

```
function refresh_Table(){
    $.ajax({
        headers:{'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
        url: "{{ route('printdate') }}",
        method: "GET",
        data:{}, 
        success:function(data)
        {

            $('#table_DTR').html(data);

            $('#table_time_records').DataTable({

                "serverSide": false,
                "retrieve": true,
                "bStateSave":true,
                "ordering": false

            });

        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            console.log(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });

}
```

My code for saving data

```
    $(document).on("click", ".btnApplyAlter", function(){

    var a = $('select[name=table_time_records_length]').val();
    validation_altered_data();    
    if(counter_alter_validation == 0)
    {
        $("select[name=table_time_records_length] option[value='365']").remove(); 
        $('select[name=table_time_records_length]').val(a).trigger('change');
        alert("Check the row you want to apply alter");
    }
    else if(checker_validation == "false")
    { 
        $("select[name=table_time_records_length] option[value='365']").remove(); 
        $('select[name=table_time_records_length]').val(a).trigger('change');
        alert(error);
    }
    else
    {
        var c = confirm("Apply this alteration?");
        if(c == true)
        {
            $('.reason').prop("disabled", false);

            $.ajax({
                headers:{'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
                url: "{{ route('applyalteration') }}",
                method: "POST",
                data: $('#alteration_data').serialize(), 
                beforeSend: function()
                {
                    document.getElementById('loader').style.display = "block";
                },
                success:function(data)
                {
                    if(data == "w")
                    {
                        alert("You don't have schedule for this day!");
                        $("select[name=table_time_records_length] option[value='365']").remove(); 
                        $('select[name=table_time_records_length]').val(a).trigger('change');   
                        $('.reason').prop("disabled", true);   
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $("select[name=table_time_records_length] option[value='365']").remove(); 
                        $('select[name=table_time_records_length]').val(a).trigger('change');     
                        alert("Alteration Applied!");

                    } 
                },
                complete:function(){
                    refresh_Table();
                    document.getElementById('loader').style.display = "none";
                }
            }); 
        }
        else{
            $("select[name=table_time_records_length] option[value='365']").remove(); 
            $('select[name=table_time_records_length]').val(a).trigger('change');
        }
    } 
});
```

My Code for Validation

```
function validation_altered_data()
{   
    var a = $('select[name=table_time_records_length]').val();
    $('select[name=table_time_records_length]').append("<option id='optioncount' value='365'></option>");
    $('select[name=table_time_records_length]').val(365).trigger('change');


    counter_alter_validation = 0;
    for(i = 1; i <=100; i++)
    {
        var sam = $('#timein' + i).val();
        var date = new Date(sam);
        month = date.getMonth()+1;

        if(month < 10)
        {
            var month_format = "0" + (date.getMonth()+1);
        }
        else
        {
            var month_format = (date.getMonth()+1);
        }

        var this_date = date.getDate();
        if(this_date >= 10)
        {
            var day_format = date.getDate();
        }
        else
        {
            var day_format = "0"+ date.getDate();
        }

        var res = date.getFullYear() + "-" + month_format + "-" + day_format;

        if($('#checkalt' + i))
        {
            if($('#checkalt' + i).prop("checked") == true)
            {
                var date_to_alter = $('#infos' + i).val().split("]]");

                counter_alter_validation++;
                if($('#txtReason_apply').val() == ""){
                    az = "1";
                    checker_validation = "false";
                    error="Reason for Alteration is Required!";
                    $("select[name=table_time_records_length] option[value='365']").remove(); 
                    $('select[name=table_time_records_length]').val(a).trigger('change');
                    break;
                }
                //If time in or time out IS EMPTY
                else if($('#timeout' + i).val() == "" || $('#timein' + i).val() == "")
                {
                    az = "2";
                    checker_validation = "false";
                    error="Time In field and Time Out field is required!";
                    $("select[name=table_time_records_length] option[value='365']").remove(); 
                    $('select[name=table_time_records_length]').val(a).trigger('change');
                    break;
                }
                else if($('#timeout' + i).val() <= $('#timein' + i).val())
                {
                    az = "3";
                    checker_validation = "false";
                    error="Time Out field must be greater than Time In field!";
                    $("select[name=table_time_records_length] option[value='365']").remove(); 
                    $('select[name=table_time_records_length]').val(a).trigger('change');
                    break;
                }
                else if(res != date_to_alter[0])
                {
                    az = "4";
                    checker_validation = "false";
                    error="Invalid Details, Check Time in and Time out!";
                    $("select[name=table_time_records_length] option[value='365']").remove(); 
                    $('select[name=table_time_records_length]').val(a).trigger('change');
                    break;
                }
                //Avoid saving the current date, If the user removes disabled attribute in the inspect elements
                else if(date_to_alter[0] == curDate)
                {
                    az = "5";
                    checker_validation = "false";
                    error="You can't alter the current date!";
                    $("select[name=table_time_records_length] option[value='365']").remove(); 
                    $('select[name=table_time_records_length]').val(a).trigger('change');
                    break;
                }
                else if($('#validateStatus' + i).val() == "Punch Altered")
                {
                    az = "6";
                    checker_validation = "false";
                    error = "You can't edit altered rows!";
                    $("select[name=table_time_records_length] option[value='365']").remove(); 
                    $('select[name=table_time_records_length]').val(a).trigger('change');
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    checker_validation = "true";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly, you didn't share the essential part of your code - the one, which refreshes the DataTable. If you happen to employ [`.draw()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw()) for that purpose, you might do `.draw(false)`

Comment: The code that refreshes the data table is the trigger change code above but I need that for validation purposes. How can I implement .draw() ?

Comment: Without seeing the wider context, it's really hard to make guesses. Append live demo to your post and it will be much easier to track down the bug.

Comment: Hello mate I updated the post. It contains code for ajax, validation and saving. This works fine with me. Not until when user confront with the validation the data table refreshes every time the system shows some incomplete fields

Comment: That's not exactly what I've been asking for (you could simply post your relevant fragments of JS, HTML, data sample in a form of live demo), however, I can see from above that you use external AJAX-call in order to retrieve source data (already in HTML format?) from server and you re-create DataTable each time upon success. First thing I would suggest is to employ [`ajax`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax) option to populate the table, thus you may benefit from the rest of DataTables API methods, options.

Comment: I know, that didn't help much, but that is, basically, the root cause - each time you get response to AJAX-call, you re-create DataTable anew with its pagination reset. I'm afraid, you're going to need to do refactoring of your app in order to get rid of this issue.

Comment: Exactly I'm recreating the dataTable from the server but if I change this structure this will be a big change for me. I tried not to do this using new dataTable and it works fine. I can use other benefit of datatable api methods. The previous developer of this system used to do this kind of coding

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192306/discussion-between-king-rg-and-user11299053).